# nginx and redirect to varnish

Tags: nginx, varnish

I have nginx config like:

```
server {
        listen *:443 ssl;
        server_name  ~^(.*\.)?domain.com$;
```

second

```
server {
        listen *:443 ssl;
        server_name  ~^(.*\.)?test.domain.com$;
```

Problem is that domain.com works fine but test.domain.com not. Redirects it to domain.com

If I simply do:

```
server_name www.domain.com$ domain.com$;
```

and

server_name test.domain.com$;

Then I always get problem with SSL

Any ideas how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a guess. Swap first server block with second server block. So `test` is not eaten by your first server block. Or make sure your first server block does not eat `test` like so: `server_name ~^(.*?[^t]?[^e]?[^s]?[^t]\.)?domain.com$;`. Or maybe better like so: `server_name ~^(.*(?<!test)\.)?domain.com$;` (negative lookbehind - supported by Nginx???)
Completly untested - but maybe you get the idea.

Make sure that you - in your regex - escape all dots `.` with backslash `\.` or brackets `[.]` to make them literally a dot character. Otherwise you serve also test-domain-com for example, which you don't want.

Im not sure if you can use regex dollar `$` in `server_name` if you don't mark it as regex `~`.